# Is any function derived by differentiation a gradient function?

Tags: calculus

I'm just getting into calculus so please forgive the naivety of the following:

If $f(x)$ can be differentiated from $F(x)$, does that in some sense make $f(x)$ a gradient function in the same way that $f'(x)$ is a gradient function when differentiated from $f(x)$?

Similarly, if $f(x)$ can be anti-differentiated from $f'(x)$, does that in some sense make $f(x)$ a primitive function in the same way that $F(x)$ can be anti-differentiated from $f(x)$?

In short, does the original function $f(x)$ represent not only that function but also (in some sense that I do not understand) a gradient function and primitive function?

Answer (score 1):

Every smooth function $f(x)$ has a derivative given by the limit definition, $f'(x)$. Every smooth function $f(x)$ also has an antiderivative given by $F(x) = \int_a^x f(s)ds$. In  this sense, there is no real special significance of a function being derivative or antiderivative of another function. All that matters is that the function is smooth.

Some functions can fail to be both a derivative and  antiderivative everywhere, though. For example, $f(x) = |x|$ has an antiderivative $F(x) = \frac{1}{2}x|x| + C$, which  is continuous everywhere, but  its  derivative, $f'(x)$, is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Extremely helpful, thank you.